# Infile streaming in switch statements

Tags: c++, string, switch-statement, ifstream, srand

How do I randomize words from a txt file into a switch statement?

I have these text files which have short words in each sentence, and I want to randomize each word that comes out of the file. Another issue, is that the switch statement doesn't return anything. What am I doing wrong?

```
 26 string grabword(char input)
 27 {
 28     string word;
 29     switch(input)
 30     {
 31         case 'A':
 32             {
 33             ifstream infile;
 34             infile.open("sample1.txt");
 35             infile >> word;
 36             return word;
 37             }
 38         case 'B':
 39             {
 40             ifstream infile;
 41             infile.open("sample2.txt");
 42             infile >> word;
 43             return word;
 44             }
 45         case 'C':
 46             {
 47             ifstream infile;
 48             infile.open("sample3.txt");
 49             infile >> word;
 50             return word;
 51             }
 52        return word;
 53 }
```

What I tried:

removing break statements.

returning actual string.

the output is nothing.

Comment: Not sure this is your problem (not sure I can reproduce your problem with the code you've given), but your `switch` appears to be missing a closing `}`.

Comment: What does your caller code look like?

Comment: The provided code is not enough for reproduction of the problem.

Comment: What value does the `switch` return on `default`?

Comment: Did you check the files were successfully opened? I guess not.

Comment: “How do I...” Read the words into a vector/array and use `rand()` and `%` to generate a random index.

Comment: @Chipster The closing brace was a pasting issue on my part. However, I have a list of words in these text files. My caller code is the input being made and then coutting the word based on the 3 cases. However, I just want to return the word at this point, the rand can come later.